# Routing issues for static files

Tags: python, python-3.x, bottle

Hi seems my static files (example: `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>` in my header [partial template]) cannot be served when I am not exactly `localhost:4242`:

- `http://localhost:4242/`: works
- `http://localhost:4242/samples`: does not work, seems Bottle use the current location to concatenate the `js/main.js`

My files are organized in such manner:

- `/runserver.py`
- `/project/static/js/main.js`

I have the following app and `static_file` use:

`static.py`

```
from project.libs.bottle import static_file
from runserver import app


# (Agnostic) Static Routes
@app.get('/<filename:path>')
def send_static(filename):
    return static_file(filename, root='project/static/')
```

`runserver.py`

```
import os
import sys

from project.libs.bottle import Bottle, run, TEMPLATE_PATH, default_app

app = default_app()

dir_name = os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])

TEMPLATE_PATH.insert(0, './project/views/layout')
TEMPLATE_PATH.insert(1, './project/views')

import project.routes.static
import project.routes.business
import project.routes.error

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run(host="localhost", port=4242, debug=True, reloader=True)
```

Comment: You really should look into using Whitenoise.  http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I managed to get create a working solution, taking in account the absolute path (it's better in case of real-world deployment, e.g. Azure) mentioned by jspcal.

Keeping the same structure (files):

`static.py`

```
# (Agnostic-ish) Static Routes
@app.get('/:path#(css|favicons|fonts|img|js)\/.+#')
def send_static(path):
    return static_file(path, root=STATIC_ROOT)
```

and

`runserver.py`

```
"""
This script runs the application using a development server.
"""

import os
import sys

from project.libs.bottle import run, TEMPLATE_PATH, default_app, debug

app = default_app()

TEMPLATE_PATH.insert(0, './project/views/layout')
TEMPLATE_PATH.insert(1, './project/views')

# routes contains the HTTP handlers for our server and must be imported.
import project.routes.static
import project.routes.business
import project.routes.error

if '--debug' in sys.argv[1:] or 'SERVER_DEBUG' in os.environ:
    # Debug mode will enable more verbose output in the console window.
    # It must be set at the beginning of the script.
    debug(True)


def wsgi_app():
    """Returns the application to make available through wfastcgi. This is used
    when the site is published to Microsoft Azure."""
    return app


PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'project/static').replace('\\', '/')
HOST = os.environ.get('SERVER_HOST', 'localhost')
try:
    PORT = int(os.environ.get('SERVER_PORT', '5555'))
except ValueError:
    PORT = 5555


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run(host=HOST, port=PORT, debug=True, reloader=True)
```

And my static files "imports":

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/main.js"></script>
```

Credits: partially inspired from a MS repo on Github here: https://github.com/Microsoft/project-python-bottle-webapp

Answer (score 0):

The `root` path for `static_file` should be an absolute path rather than a relative one, because the working directory may not be the same as the project directory.

```
return static_file(filename, root='project/static/')
```

This route also matches all paths

```
@app.get('/<filename:path>')
```

Comment: Agree for the root path, however in my case the issue has nothing to do with that, it seems more related to argument of the decorator @app.get('/<filename:path>')
If the root path was the issue it would not even work for the localhost:4242 which is not my case.